# Extract Data Using awk from multiple files

Tags: search, awk, grep, extract

i have 1000 files like this :

text1.txt

```
<span class="store-time">OPEN SINCE <em>Aug 9, 2010</em></span>
```

text2.txt

```
<span class="store-time">OPEN SINCE <em>Aug 9, 2012</em></span>
```

i want extract all Dates from 1000 files, each one in new line like this :

```
Aug 9, 2010
Aug 9, 2012
...
```

Comment: Choose the right tool first. I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Comment: how that ! can you give me example please

Comment: `xmlstarlet select --template --copy-of '//span/em/text()' -n text*.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that your files all have exactly this format, you can use a simple `sed` expression

```
sed -E -e 's/^<span class="store-time">OPEN SINCE <em>([A-Z][a-z]+ *[0-9]+, *[0-9]+)<\/em><\/span>/\1/'
```

It just finds the start of your line, followed by something that looks like a date (letters followed by a space and a number, followed by a comma, and again a number), and the end of your line.
`cat` all your files and send the result to `sed` input and you get the list of dates.

But as pointed in the comments, parsing xml files can be problematic (see for instance [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) ). If the xml tags are spread on several lines, the script will fail extracting the information, for instance with the following data

```
<span class="store-time">
OPEN SINCE <em>Aug 9, 2012</em>
</span>
```

To deal with such situations, there are more more powerful tools. As the collection of tools `xmlstarlet` or `perl` class like `XML::libXML`. THey are able to perform a more crash-proof parsing but they are more complex to use.

If you are definitely sure that all your files have the proper formatting, the sed script can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for parsing XML tools such as `awk` or `sed` are for sure not the first choice because they are rather line-based and XML isn't.

To get your job done in awk you could use something like:

```
awk '$0 ~ /<span class="store-time">.*/ {gsub(/^.*<em>/,"",$0) gsub(/<\/em>.*/,"",$0); print $0}' *.html
```

This command takes all html files (*.html) and searches for lines starting with `<span class="store-time">`.
It then replaces everything from the start of the line up to the first `<em>` by an empty string. It does the same for everything after `</em>` (including `</em>`)